# method name not conflict with property name in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. While seeing this code:

```
var obj = {
    foo : function foo(){console.log("foo");}

}
```

I was wondering why the 2 `foo` names did not create conflict ?

Comment: One `foo` is a property, the other a function name -- two different concepts.

Comment: Because it's a key-value pair. If you were to add the same key twice, then it'd create a conflict or rather overwrite the first value with the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the `key` name, and the other one is the *function* name:

```
var obj = {
    foo : function foo(){console.log("foo");}
 // ^              ^
 // Key            Name
}   |              |
    v              |
obj.foo.name <-----+
// => foo
```

It is something similar to:

```
function foo () {console.log("foo");}
var obj = { foo: foo }
// or simply
var obj = { foo }
```

> #### [`Function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)
>
> A Function object's read-only name property indicates the function's name as specified when it was created, or it may be rather anonymous or ''(an empty string) for functions created anonymously.

Comment: this name `foo` is stored as property of function object ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Yes, the name is a property of the function object. The key name is a property of the `obj` object.